# subtracting greatest possible prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, prime-numbers

Let $A$ be a set of positive integers, $\min A:=a_0$. For $x\geq a_0$ define $f(x)=x-a$, where $a\leq x$, $a\in A$ is the maximal possible. Then for a positive integer $x$ the iterations $x$, $f(x)$, $f(f(x))$, $\dots$ finally come to some element of the set $\{0,1,\dots,a_0-1\}$. Denote this final number by $F(x)$. For example, if $A$ is the set of primes, $F(x)$ equals either 0 or 1. Do there always exist frequencies $\lim \frac{|F^{-1}(s)\cap [1,N]|}{N}$ for $s=0,1,\dots,a_0-1$? If not, what is a criterion of existing of such frequencies? Do they exist, say, for $A$=primes?

Comment: sorry? I do not see typos

Comment: ah, ok
my dictionaries claim that substraction is also ok (see for example http://www.answers.com/topic/substraction)

Comment: That dictionary marks it [Obs.] (obsolete), which means it's not used in modern works.

Answer (score 6):

This is Sloane's [A121559](http://oeis.org/classic/A121559), which essentially iterates [A064722](http://oeis.org/classic/A064722).  The behavior is controlled by the (appropriately weighted) distribution of prime gaps below $N.$

Heuristically, with $\ell=1-1/\log N$, you'd expect something like $(1-\ell)\left(1+\ell^3+\ell^5+\ell^7+\ell^{11}+\cdots\right)$ $1$s below $N,$ where the exponents are $1$ less than the locations of the $1$s. You can stop the sum around $\log^2 N$.

Comment: +1 for finding it in Sloane.

Answer (score 6):

It is easy to construct $A$ for which the limit does not exist. Consider the following set $A$. Include all even numbers in the intervals $[10^n, 10^{n+1}]$ for even $n=0,2,...$, and all numbers divisible by 3 in the intervals $(10^n,10^{n+1})$ for odd $n$. Now if $N=10^k$ with $k$ even then the probability of 0 is $\ge .9$, and if $k$ is odd, then the probability of $1$ is $\ge .9*1/3=.3$.  In general, the limit exists if the intervals between consecutive numbers in $A$ are "uniformly spaced". In particular, if $A$ is a set of primes, I do not know how to show that the limit exists. It may be a hard number theory problem. For example, we know (Green and Tao) that the set of primes contains arbitrary long arithmetic progressions, but it is not clear (to me) how often these occur and how often progressions start at relatively small numbers and are relatively long.

Comment: Thanks, the question about arbitrary $A$ was indeed naive. But which information do we really need about differences of neighbour terms? Specification of this question is the case of primes.

Comment: I guess you need to consider the probability of 1 for a number below $a_n$, the $n$-th number in $A$. Assume that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is always $\lt 2$ (as in the case of primes). Then the probability of $1$, $p(a_{n+1})$, is the probability that your number is $\lt a_n$ times $p(a_n)$ plus the probability that your number is $\gt a_n$ times $p(a_{n+1}-a_n)$. This gives some sort of recurrent equation. 

Comment: I suspect that modulo RH the limit exists and the probability of 1 is about .65... (an empirical calculation for $N=5*10^7$). I do not know whether known, weaker than RH, statements would suffice. I hope that specialists in number theory can help.  

Comment: @Mark: Did you mean the probability of 0?  The probability of 1 is clearly at most 1/2.

Comment: @Charles: Why $1/2$?

Comment: @Mark: Because A121560(n) > 0.

Comment:  @Mark: FWIW, my calculations near 10^1000 support a probability of 0 around 0.65....

Comment: @Charles
By the way, how do you treat it up to 10^1000? 

Comment: @Fedor: Random sampling. I wanted to make sure this wasn't just an artifact of using small numbers like 5e7.  Unfortunately, for this problem the next step up would be something like exp(5e7), which I can't do, so I went as high as reasonable instead.

Comment: but how do you find the largest prime in greedy algorithm?

Comment: @Fedor: The best method is to sieve a block of numbers before n (from ln n to ln^2 n, depending on how cautious you want to be; 2 ln n would be reasonable) by the first few primes (maybe up to 10^3 or 10^6), then test each remaining number with Miller-Rabin, then (if desired) prove primality with BPSW (below 2^64), APR-CL, or ECPP.

Practically speaking, I use Pari's precprime() command.

Comment: @Charles: I have checked all numbers below $5*10^7$. The probability of 1 is $.63..$. I do not understand your argument that it should be $\le 1/2$. 

Comment: I get the same number that you get as the probability of 1 as the probability of 0.  1 - 0.63... <= 1/2, so it works in my interpretation.  A121560 is the length of blocks of 0s between 1s in this sequence.  If the sequence strictly alternated 0s and 1s, it would be 1,1,1,1,...; if there were ever two consecutive 1s then A121560 would contain a 0.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this is effectively the question about (greedy) systems of numeration for the natural numbers. These are well understood in the case when $A$ satisfies some recurrence relation -- like the Fibonacci sequence (Zeckendorf) or the denominators $q_n$ of the CF convergents for some irrational $\alpha$ (Ostrowski).

If $A$ grows subexponentially, this is usually not good news for the ``ergodic'' questions like this.

Comment: Would you please give more details and references?

Comment: Off the top of my head:

A. Fraenkel, Systems of numeration, Amer. Math. Monthly 92 (1985), 105–114.

P. Grabner, P. Liardet and R. Tichy, Odometers and systems of numeration, Acta Arith. 80 (1995), 103–123.

My own survey paper (http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nikita/ad.pdf) may be also somewhat useful, though it is mostly about systems of numeration for the reals and vectors rather than the integers. 

Comment: yes, exactly, that's greedy representation of $x$ as a sum of primes (in general setting, of elements of $A$)

thanks for your links!

Comment: Sure, no problem. 